# Native-base Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a Text Component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am getting this error with my code:

```
export default class AddExpensePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Title>Add Expense</Title>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <InputGroup borderType='underline' >
                        <Input placeholder='Item Name' />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <Button primary> Testing </Button>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

**And this is the code on their official documentation:**

```
export default class ButtonExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    // NativeBase default style
                    <Button> Click Me! </Button>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

I don't get why I have this error because supposedly I do not have to wrap the text "Testing" in Text tags?

Comment: The button should be wrapped inside <Text>. check this link https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref

Comment: The text should be wrapped by <Text> inside <Button>. check this link https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap in Text tag like:

```js
<Content>
      <Button>
        <Text>Click Me!</Text>
      </Button>
</Content>
```

[DOC](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref)

Comment: I think I might have gotten the documentation of an older version. Thanks!